# Parameters too long using Node.js & HTTPS for Email Audit API

Tags: node.js, rest, https, request, google-email-audit-api

I'm using Email Audit API to monitor emails of my company. Unfortunately, I can't upload my public key as asked here following the instructions here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/auth.

In that example, I will use the public key (base64 encoded) given on the google page :

```
LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQR1AgUFVCTElDIEtFWSBCTE9DSy0tLS0tDQpWZXJzaW9uOiBHbn
VQRyB2MS40LjEwIChHTlUvTGludXgpDQoNCm1RRU5CRXJXYUQ0QkNBQ3QybmdmczYv
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```

Here is my code :

```
var params = 
    "<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>"+
        "<apps:property name='publicKey' value='"+key+"'/>"+
    "</atom:entry>";


// An object of options to indicate where to post to
var post_options = {
    host: 'apps-apis.google.com',
    path: '/a/feeds/compliance/audit/publickey/' + encodeURIComponent(domain),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8',
    }
};

// Set up the request
var post_req = https.request(post_options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("REPONSE");
        console.log("-------");
        console.log(chunk);
    });
});

// post the data
post_req.write(params);
post_req.end();
```

And as the result come as multiples i guess my params are too long :

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppsForYourDomainErrors>
  <error errorCode="1411" invalidInput="LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQR1AgUFVCTElDIEtFWSBCTE9DSy0tLS0tDQpWZXJzaW9uOiBHbn VQRyB2MS40LjEwIChHTlUvTGludXgpDQoNCm1RRU5CRXJXYUQ0QkNBQ3QybmdmczYv K1FPR1lieE5iYzNnTG5YSHRxcDdOVFRYTlc0U0pvKy9BMW9VWm9HeEENClF4NnpGWG hRLzhNWFc2Nis4U1RTMVlxTkpPQVJGdGpiSUtQd2pyZGN1a2RQellWS0dacmUwUmF4 Q25NeUNWKzYNCkY0WU5RRDFVZWdIVHUyd0NHUjF1aVlPZkx4VWE3L2RvNnMzMVdSVE g4dmJ0aVBZOS82b2JFSXhEakR6S0lxWU8NCnJ2UkRXcUFMQllrbE9rSjNIYmdmeWw0 MkVzbkxpQWhTK2RNczJQQ0RpMlgwWkpDUFo4ZVRqTHNkQXRxVlpKK1INCldDMUozVU R1RmZtY3BzRFlSdFVMOXc2WU10bGFwQys5bW1KM0FCRUJBQUcwVjBSaGMyaGxjaUJV WlhOMElDaFUNCmRHVnlNa0JrWVhOb1pYSXRhSGxrTFhSbGMzUXVZMjl0UG9rQk9BUV RBUUlBSWdVQ1N0Wm9QZ0liRFFZTENRZ0gNCmsxOVFja1Rwd0Jkc2tFWXVtRnZtV3Zl NVVYMlNWVjdmek9DMG5adGdGeHRaR2xKaEdtanNBM3J4RlRsYitJcmENCldaYXlYQ1 dZaUN6ZDdtOXo1L0t5R0QyR0ZUSy85NG1kbTI1TjZHWGgvYjM1cElGWlhCSS9yWmpy WXJoWVJCRnUNCkd0ekdGSXc5QUFuRnlVekVVVVZmUFdVdEJlNXlITVc1NEM2MG5Iaz V4WUlhNnFGaGlMcDRQWXFa
REPONSE
-------
Q3JZWDFpSXMNCmZSUk9GQT09DQo9U1RIcg0KLS0tLS1F TkQgUEdQIFBVQkxJQyBLRVkgQkxPQ0stLS0tLQ==" reason="EncryptionPublicKeyInvalidFormat" />
</AppsForYourDomainErrors>
```

As it seems the response is a divided several parts, i guess the problem come from response.write() .. So i tried adding in the headers :

```
'Content-Length': params.length
```

And still the same problem :

```
REPONSE
-------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppsForYourDomainErrors>
  <error errorCode="1411" invalidInput="LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQR1AgUFVCTElDIEtFWSBCTE9DSy0tLS0tDQpWZXJzaW9uOiBHbn VQRyB2MS40LjEwIChHTlUvTGludXgpDQoNCm1RRU5CRXJXYUQ0QkNBQ3QybmdmczYv  K1FPR1lieE5iYzNnTG5YSHRxcDdOVFRYTlc0U0pvKy9BMW9VWm9HeEENClF4NnpGWG hRLzhNWFc2Nis4U1RTMVlxTkpPQVJGdGpiSUtQd2pyZGN1a2RQellWS0dacmUwUmF4 Q25NeUNWKzYNCkY0WU5RRDFVZWdIVHUyd0NHUjF1aVlPZkx4VWE3L2RvNnMzMVdSVE g4dmJ0aVBZOS82b2JFSXhEakR6S0lxWU8NCnJ2UkRXcUFMQllrbE9rSjNIYmdmeWw0 MkVzbkxpQWhTK2RNczJQQ0RpMlgwWkpDUFo4ZVRqTHNkQXRxVlpKK1INCldDMUozVU R1RmZtY3BzRFlSdFVMOXc2WU10bGFwQys5bW1KM0FCRUJBQUcwVjBSaGMyaGxjaUJV WlhOMElDaFUNCmRHVnlNa0JrWVhOb1pYSXRhSGxrTFhSbGMzUXVZMjl0UG9rQk9BUV RBUUlBSWdVQ1N0Wm9QZ0liRFFZTENRZ0gNCmsxOVFja1Rwd0Jkc2tFWXVtRnZtV3Zl NVVYMlNWVjdmek9DMG5adGdGeHRaR2xKaEdtanNBM3J4RlRsYitJcmENCldaYXlYQ1 dZaUN6ZDdtOXo1L0t5R0QyR0ZUSy85NG1kbTI1TjZHWGgvYjM1cElGWlhCSS9yWmpy WXJoWVJCRnUNCkd0ekdGSXc5QUFuRnlVekVVVVZmUFdVdEJlNXlITVc1NEM2MG5Iaz V4WUlhNnFGaGlMcDRQWXF
REPONSE
-------
aQ3JZWDFpSXMNCmZSUk9GQT09DQo9U1RIcg0KLS0tLS1F TkQgUEdQIFBVQkxJQyBLRVkgQkxPQ0stLS0tLQ==" reason="EncryptionPublicKeyInvalidFormat" />
</AppsForYourDomainErrors>
```

I'm running out of ideas, any help would be welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using http://unirest.io/nodejs.html.

Now it's working perfectly. Here is the code for those who might want it :

```
function uploadPublicKey(domain, key, token) {
    var params = 
        "<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>"+
            "<apps:property name='publicKey' value='"+key+"'/>"+
        "</atom:entry>";


    unirest
    .post('https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/publickey/' + encodeURIComponent(domain))
    .headers({
        'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length': params.length}
        )
    .send(params)
    .end(function (response) {
        console.log(response.body);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in your base64-encoded string (this is shown in the response). Remove the whitespace (e.g. `key.replace(/\s/g, '')`) and you should be ok.

Comment: Thx for the answer but the problem doesn't come from here, I already tried that still the same problem ; just there is more characters in the first response.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/auth#uploading_key),

> An attempt to upload an invalid key will return with **error code 1411** (EncryptionPublicKeyInvalidFormat).

Also noted that, **invalid OpenPGP keys are generally the most common cause of errors.** For this, please try to follow the summary of the step-by-step instructions to [generate a public key](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/auth#generating_key) for the Email Audit API. Last step mentioned about **double checking that you copy all the lines, including the header and not adding any extra line.**

Lastly, in [uploading the public key](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/auth#uploading_key), start by creating an XML entry with the base64 encoded public key as shown in the example below:

```
<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>
<apps:property name="publicKey" value="the base64 Encoded Key"/>
</atom:entry>
```

Send an HTTP `POST` request to the 'publickey' feed URI in your Google Apps domain:

```
POST https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/publickey/{domain name}
```

If successful, the server returns a 201 CREATED status code found in the Google Data API [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) documentation.

Please try going through the given documentations for more information including details on authorization protocols.